# Open modal with # in url

Tags: jquery, url, modal-dialog

Im sorry for this probably dumm question, but I want to simply open modals with # in the url. So if i call www.domain.com/#modal1 it will open the page with the modal poped-up already.

Oh Im using jquery.

Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Many application frameworks (I'm partial to [backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/)) use some kind of router to accomplish this, but you could fake your own by checking `window.hash` and running an appropriate function:

```
function popModal() {
  // code to pop up modal dialog
}

var hash = window.location.hash;
if (hash.substring(1) == 'modal1') {
  popModal();
}
```

​​

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer,

This is my implementation:

```
function bf_hashCheck(){
var hash = window.location.hash;        
if (hash){
    if (jQuery(hash).css('display')=='none'){           
        jQuery(hash).fadeIn(300);
    }
}
}
```

Just a simple example