# How can I write a router to open a Joomla Squeezebox modal from a URL parameter?

Tags: javascript, joomla, mootools, squeezebox

I have a Joomla site which uses Squeezebox which the default modal javascript for Joomla.

I've been using Squeezebox with template overrides. For example, I have a link that looks on every page that's part of the template override:

```
<a href="http://www.viddler.com/embed/cd1b1bc5/?f=1&autoplay=1&player=full&secret=104492144&loop=0&nologo=1&hd=1" class="modal vid-primary" rel="{url:'http://www.viddler.com/embed/cd1b1bc5/?f=1&autoplay=1&player=full&secret=104492144&loop=0&nologo=1&hd=1', handler: 'iframe', size: {x:741, y:459} }" style="display: block; position: relative;">
```

These links open a video in a modal.

What I need to do is to be able to open this video onLoad IF a URL parameter is present. For example:

http://mysite.com/page.html?vidload=vidload

So I need a router that will handle this. I [found something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022543/open-modal-with-in-url) close to what I'm after, but can't quite figure out how to make it work. Here's what I've got so far:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
 function popModal() {
  SqueezeBox.open($('vid-primary'), {
        handler: 'adopt'
    });
}

var hash = window.location.hash;
if (hash.substring(1) == 'vidload') {
  popModal();
}

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Include Modal library in template override:

```
<?php JHtml::_('behavior.modal'); ?>
```

Use links like this:

```
<a class="modal" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 800, y: 500}}" title="Modal box title" href="[your link]" >open</a>
```

More in 
[Squeezebox Documentation](http://digitarald.de/project/squeezebox/1-1/showcase/iframed/) and [JHtml::_('behaviour.modal') options](http://docs.joomla.org/API16%3aJHtmlBehavior/modal#Examples)

Update:
I think Adidi's answer below is what you are after.
If you load MooTools More anyway, you may use [URI class](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Types/URI#URI%3aget):

```
var uri = new URI (location.href);
if (uri.getData('vidload') == 'vidload') {
    SqueezeBox.open($('vid-primary'), { handler: 'adopt' });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm after - modals are working just fine, if you want to click to open or get a modal to open onload every time the page loads. I need to get a URL parameter and get it to trigger the modal onLoad.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the hash and it's empty according to what you want,
If what you need is a function that get querystring parmaeter you can use this simple function:

```
function getURLParam(key,target){
    var value = '';
    if(!target){
        target = location.href;
    }

    var pattern = key + '=([^&#]+)';
    var o_reg = new RegExp(pattern,'i');
    var matches = o_reg.exec(target);
    if(matches && matches[1]){
        value = matches[1];
    }

    return value;
}

if(getURLParam('vidload') == 'vidload'){
  popModal();
}
```