# auto open modal with w3.css

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog, anchor, w3.css

So i am trying to open my modal when a password/username is entered wrong. 
I have searched google but i can't come up with a good solution on how to do this with `W3.CSS`.
My modal is being opened by an `ID` called `"id01"` and then i tried a small javascript that i found on stackoverflow in : [Open modal with # in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022543/open-modal-with-in-url).
After trying to edit it with the help of `W3.CSS` to :

```
function popModal() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

var hash = window.location.hash;
if (hash.substring(1) == 'id01') {
    popModal();
}
```

It still didn't work. So to make a long story short. How do i make the modal go open when there is like : `"#1234"` in the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                //console.log( window.location.href );

                if(window.location.href.indexOf("#1234") > -1) {
                    alert("your url contains #1234");
                    popModal();
                }



            });
```